# Auto generate id in java and total id count

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, auto-increment

Actually, i got a stress in this problem.
I have an image

[image]

So Im getting 2 problems here.

1. How can I insert the auto generate id with format starting "T00001"?
2. How can i count total number of ID when i display with datas in table.

Im a new one in Java MVC GUI. Anyone can help me get a good solution.
Thanks in advanced

And this is my Data Access Object file.

> package model;
>       import java.sql.*;
>       import java.util.ArrayList;
>       import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class SchoolDAO{
    Conexion conexion;

    public SchoolDAO(){

    conexion = new Conexion();
}


        /////INSERT TEACHER
        public String insertTeacher(String tbno, String tbname, String tbphone, String tbqualification, String tbexp){
    String rptaAdd = null; 
try {
    Connection accessDB  = conexion.getConexion(); 
    CallableStatement cs  = accessDB.prepareCall ("{call teacher_insert(?,?,?,?,?)}");
                  cs.setString(1, tbno);
                  cs.setString(2, tbname);
                  cs.setString(3, tbphone);
                  cs.setString(4, tbqualification);
                  cs.setString(5, tbexp);

    int numFAeffect = cs.executeUpdate();

            if(numFAeffect>0){
                rptaAdd ="Add successful.";
            }
    } catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
}
    return rptaAdd;
}

        public ArrayList<School> listTeacher(){
    ArrayList listaTeacher = new ArrayList();
    School school; 
    try{
    Connection accessDB = conexion.getConexion();
    PreparedStatement ps = accessDB.prepareStatement("select * from teacher");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
         school = new School();
             school.setTno(rs.getString(1));
             school.setTname(rs.getString(2));
             school.setTphone(rs.getString(3));
             school.setTqualification(rs.getString(4));
             school.setTexp(rs.getString(5));
             listaTeacher.add(school);

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        return listaTeacher;

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Send the ID as a number incremented from a sequence or other mechanism that will get you auto incrementing numbers with "T" + left padded string with zeroes to the desired value.

   `"T" + StringUtils.leftpad(id + "", 5, "0"); // your ID`
2. Select the count (*) from teacher table.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But with Ans1: Where can i insert your code in my program?

Comment: So when you call your insertTeacher method you can use the line from the answer as teacher_id

Comment: Actually, i just insert only 
>CallableStatement cs  = accessDB.prepareCall ("{call teacher_insert(\"T\" + StringUtils.leftpad(tbno + \"\", 5, \"0\"),?,?,?,?)}");
Coudnt run the addfunction
Or must to do something more?

Comment: You should use the new ID as a string. Do not concatenate java code.